# No returning back after starting an intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this intent

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

     Intent intent =  getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");

     Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/symphonyrecords");

     if (intent != null) {  

     intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
     intent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
     startActivity(intent);

    } else {

     intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "com.instagram.android"));
     startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
});
```

After onClick, intent (Instagram) starts but when i press back for return, my app is closed

Do i have to change/add something here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `startActivityForResult()` and assign a `KEY_CODE` so you can handle what happened outside of your activity scope.

Android documentation:

> Starting another activity doesn't have to be one-way. You can also
>   start another activity and receive a result back. To receive a result,
>   call startActivityForResult() (instead of startActivity()).
>
> For example, your app can start a camera app and receive the captured
>   photo as a result. Or, you might start the People app in order for the
>   user to select a contact and you'll receive the contact details as a
>   result.
>
> Of course, the activity that responds must be designed to return a
>   result. When it does, it sends the result as another Intent object.
>   Your activity receives it in the onActivityResult() callback.

You can read more here: [Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)